# How to disable SSH in GitBlit and use only HTTP and HTTPS instead

Tags: git, ssh, gitblit

I try to disable SSH in GitBlit and to hide it from the Repository-URL, e.g. ssh://user@domain:29418/MyProj.git. 
I need only http and https access, e.g. https://user@domain/gitblit/MyProj.git

GitBlit is running on the JBoss 4.

Thanks for Your Help.

Answer (score 6):

set the port to number smaller then 0 in order to disable it.

More info can be found here:
http://gitblit.com/properties.html

```
# The port for serving the SSH service. <= 0 disables this service.
# On Unix/Linux systems, ports < 1024 require root permissions.
# Recommended value: 29418
# 
# SINCE 1.5.0
# RESTART REQUIRED
git.sshPort = 29418
```

Comment: It works. Sorry! I have replaced the default 'baseFolder' with a different but the settings made in the 'gitblit.properties' in the old directory.